# Как получить id primary зная ее имя?

Tags: mongodb

Мне нужно получить id primary node, зная ее имя в mongodb. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал так:

```
rs.status().members.find('name': \"node_name\")
```

так:

```
rs.status().members.find({name: \"node_name\"})
```

и так:

```
rs.status().members.find({name: db.hello().primary})
```

Но все эти варианты выдают ошибку

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","

на месте двоеточия. Если получить нужный member можно потом добавить к нему ._id

Comment: В качестве развития, что такое `primary node`?

Comment: @ksa Главная нода replSet. Та, с которой реплики (secondary) берут данные. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-primary/